# Does Mirror API support Node JS..?

Tags: google-mirror-api

I have a service built entirely in Node JS. So, how can I integrate that with Mirror API, say Share Entities..?
I mean, is it as good as parsing just the JSON..?

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way is to use the `googleapis` package to get access to the "mirror v1" package. See https://github.com/burcu/google-api-nodejs-client for more info on the package and then you can do something like:

```
var google = require('googleapis');

google.discover('mirror', 'v1' ).execute(function(err,client){
  console.log( client );
});
```

To get the `client.mirror` object, which will have `client.mirror.timeline`, `client.mirror.subscriptions`, etc.

(I'm working on sample code to illustrate this. I'll try to update this answer when it is ready.)

Comment: cool...that pretty much answers my query...i can go ahead and use it.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, because Google Glass apps run in the cloud, and everything is done through REST, any server is capable of being a Glass app, no matter were it runs or what language it is.

In other words, **yes**.

Comment: yup, i thought it would be possible as its gonna be just another web service..wanted to make sure..thnx anyway..